# Vercel/NextJS deployment does not wait to send email via Azure before finishing serverless function

Tags: typescript, azure, email, next.js, vercel

I am trying to send a registration/account activation email upon a user's registration. Email is sent properly via Azure's email services when running on localhost, but deployments live on Vercel do not send the email (user is successfully made/entered in database though).

Have seen/read up on other problems with Vercel hosted deployments and email sending issues, typically caused by the serverless function returning once receiving a response (typically before an email is sent out). However with Microsoft's Azure Email Communication services I can't seem to get the right behavior with await/async function calls. Have not seen any other fixes/solutions relating to Azure so was hoping to see if anyone can suggest a fix for this specific issue.

[Link to similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725033/sendgrid-emails-wont-send-when-deployed-to-vercel)

Takeaways from above link:

- If you're on free tier, each request must resolve in 10 seconds (for pro its 60),
- Vercel seems to instantly terminate a serverless function once a response is returned, aka side effects that are not finished will cease to run.

They simply fixed via adding an await to sending the email, but Azure's specific email client behavior already has

```
const poller = await emailClient.beginSend(emailMessage);
const result = await poller.pollUntilDone();
```

which should have the whole thing await before returning and thus should not end the serverless function early before the email is sent.

Here is the bulk of the email sending code within the `api/register/route.ts` file.

```
export async function POST(
  request: Request, 
) {
  const connectionString = process.env['COMMUNICATION_SERVICES_CONNECTION_STRING'];
  const emailClient = new EmailClient(connectionString);

  async function main() {
    const emailMessage = {
      senderAddress: "DoNotReply@filler.com",
      content: {
          subject: ``,
          text: ``,
          html: ``,
      },
      recipients: {
          to: [{ address: user.email }], // don't worry this is defined, cut out majority of code above for shortness
      },
    };

    const poller = await emailClient.beginSend(emailMessage);
    const result = await poller.pollUntilDone();
    console.log("Email sent: %s", result);
  }

  main().catch(console.error);

  // setTimeout(() => { return NextResponse.json(user); }, 3000);
  return NextResponse.json(user);
}
```

I've tried a pure timeout buffer before returning a response as it seems that could've worked, but it resulted in an error being thrown and caught here and in the outside caller of this api route.ts.

I expected this to allow for the email to be sent before the serverless function terminates (and it might work) but was having issues with errors being thrown

"error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:261:61)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, needed to add
`await` before `main().catch(console.error);` as main is the async function I am calling within the overall POST request.

Original line:

```
main().catch(console.error);
```

The modified line is:

```
await main().catch(console.error);
```

This allows for the function to run until the email is sent.

For the purpose of user registration, this email send logic likely needs to be split up from the logic registering/adding the user to database as it causes the outside registration modal to hang as it waits for the email to send. It would probably be better to place this email send function after the user is created in the database and the modal is set to close.

```
axios.post("/api/register", data)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.data.error) {
      toast.error(response.data.error.message);
    } else {
      toast.success(`Registered! Verify email to activate your account.`, {
        duration: 6000,
      });
      setStep(STEPS.BASICS)
      registerModal.onClose();
      loginModal.onOpen();
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error) {
      toast.error(error.response.data.error);
    } else {
      toast.error('Registration failed. Please try again.');
    }
  })
  .finally(() => {
    setIsLoading(false);
  });
```

Comment: better fix was to just surround the whole email logic in a `try {} catch {}` rather than defining async main function and calling it with await.